# Can I use "short of being exhaustive" in this case?

Tags: expressions, word-usage, meaning-in-context, phrase-requests

I'm making a list and want the reader to know that this list is not complete, that it is only a part of a larger list...
Is it correct to say "this list is short of being exhaustive" in this case?

Is there a better way to say it?

Thanks

PS: on another note, can I say "this list is anything BUT exhaustive"?

Comment: I would just say "This list is not exhaustive."

Comment: Something wrong with "This list is incomplete..." or "Amongst the many possibilities considered..."?

Comment: Another option (besides Caleb Bernard's very sensible one)  is to say that the list is "partial" or "selective."

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, guys.

Can I still say "this list is anything BUT exhaustive"?

Comment: Okay. It's not exhaustive, can it be a *salad topping*, *floor wax*, *grout cleaner*, *rodent repellent*, *dessert topping*, *pesticide*? Because clearly those are things that list might be (since it's not exhaustive).

Comment: @RichardMax, I would say "This list is anything BUT exhaustive" is fine, although highly, highly informal.

Comment: @Elliot Your list makes me think of crumbs on the floor/ants in the kitchen :)

Comment: If you say "anything but exhaustive" I would infer that it is _far from_ exhaustive—perhaps less than half the possibilities might have been mentioned.

Comment: One might say "less than exhaustive".

Answer (score 1):

You could say,

> *items include but are not limited to [list].*

Or, at some point before or after the list, you could simply say,

> *this list is **not comprehensive**.*

EDIT: I realise that I haven't really answered your question, sorry!

I think the phrase *this list is short of being exhaustive* conveys that *almost* all the items are included, or at least all the relevant ones, so if that's what you mean to say then by all means use it. You could add some further explanation: *... but includes all the salient points,* for example.

As stated in one of the comments, *this list is anything but exhaustive* conveys that the list is *far* from complete, and emphasises that it should not be relied upon as to the complete content of the list.

Answer (score 0):

This is a partial, very limited, list.

```
par·tial
ˈpärSHəl/
adjective
adjective: partial
    1.
    existing only in part; incomplete.
    "a question to which we have only partial answers"
    synonyms:   incomplete, limited, qualified, imperfect, fragmentary, unfinished
    "a partial recovery"
    antonyms:   complete, total
    2.
    favoring one side in a dispute above the other; biased.
    "the paper gave a distorted and very partial view of the situation"
    synonyms:   biased, prejudiced, partisan, one-sided, slanted, skewed, colored, unbalanced
    "a very partial view of the situation"
```

Comment: Hi, please provide the link and the source for the reference you are citing.